# android application crashes when opening csv file in activity

Tags: android, csv

I'm using [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) in my application but whenever I try to read my csv file, the application crashes.

Here's the code I am using:

```
        String next[] = {};
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("sample.csv")));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Whenever I try to comment out these lines, the app works just fine. What can be the possible problem with this?

Here's the log whenever I click the button for opening the new activity that uses the code above:

```
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.meralco.pms/com.meralco.pms.SinActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.meralco.pms.SinActivity.onCreate(SinActivity.java:36)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: you may not be getting asset sample.csv for InputStreamReader.where in asset is your csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Go through entire log.

```
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 11:59:28.147: E/AndroidRuntime(825):  at com.meralco.pms.SinActivity.onCreate(SinActivity.java:36)
```

See Line number 36 if you have done any mistake there.Post onCreate code so can have a look

Hope this helps.

Comment: went through the log and saw that line 36 points to

`textResult.setText("SINNNNNNNNNSSSSSSS");`  


    <TextView android:src="@+id/text" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="lols"/>  


figured `android:src="@+id/text"` should be ` `android:id="@+id/text"`  

changed it and now my code works! :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader CSVFile = 
        new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("sample.csv")));

  String dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); 


  while (dataRow != null){
   String[] dataArray = dataRow.split(",");
   for (String item:dataArray) { 
      System.out.print(item + "\t"); 
   }
   System.out.println(); 
   dataRow = CSVFile.readLine(); 
  }
  // Close the file once all data has been read.
  CSVFile.close();
```

**or****
Using CSV Reader

```
 CsvReader products = new CsvReader("sample.csv");

                products.readHeaders();

                while (products.readRecord())
                {
                    String productID = products.get("field1");
                    String productName = products.get("field2");
                    String supplierID = products.get("field3");
                    String categoryID = products.get("field4");
    }
    products.close();
```

Hope it helps u